# Is there a way to count down more than 1 day using UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, datepicker

I'm using UIDatePicker's countdown timer mode (UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer) to handle countdowns. However the default picker only goes up to 24 hours.

Is there a way to get around this? Or is there any existing library that does something like this?